# R minimum variance portfolio: solve non invertible matrix

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization, portfolio, quadprog

I want to solve an **optimization problem** regarding a **minimum variance portfolio** using R as shortly described on this website: http://enricoschumann.net/R/minvar.htm

The problem is: the matrix I want to use has **more columns (=assets) than rows (=observations)**, which is why it is not positive definite and non-invertible.

You can recreate this problem by taking the opposite values for the variables as on the website, which results in the following:

```
nO <- 10L  ## number of observations
nA <- 100L  ## number of assets
```

```
mData <- array(rnorm(nO * nA, sd = 0.05), 
               dim = c(nO, nA)) #Creating sample stock observations

library("quadprog")
aMat <- array(1, dim = c(1,nA))
bVec <- 1
zeros <- array(0, dim = c(nA,1))

solQP <- solve.QP(cov(mData), zeros, t(aMat), bVec, meq = 1) #Minimize optimization
solQP$solution
```

which results in the following **error**:

```
 matrix D in quadratic function is not positive definite!
```

Does anybody know other functions to solve the optimization with mData **or** ways to make mData invertible without losing information?

The desired result are the weights for each asset for the minimum variance portfolio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(Matrix)
Q = nearPD(cov(mData))$mat
```

and then use `Q` instead of `cov(mData)`.

There is also an alternative Mean-Variance model based on adjusted returns that handles your case directly. See [link](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2018/04/covariance-matrix-not-positive-definite.html). Unfortunately, this is not so easy to implement using QuadProg ([link](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2020/09/fix-non-positive-semi-definite.html)).

Comment: I looked at the alternative formulation in the link you
provided.  Suppose I have a returns matrix `R` of size
`T` times `n` (number of observations times number of
assets). Then your model, IIUC, minimises `(Rx)'IRx =
x'R'Rx`. But then, if `R` does not have full column rank,
neither does `R'R`.

Comment: The main problem with QuadProg is that it wants (1) a strictly positive definite matrix (not positive-semi definite) and (2) all variables need to be quadratic. Most QP solvers are not like this. A simple workaround just for QuadProg is to add a small diagonal value to Q for the linear variables. Again, better QP solvers are widely available that do not need this.